# Mysql variable in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, nagios

I'd like to create a script that check a variable on my mysql db, let me explain better.

I have this query:

> SELECT *  FROM my.backup
>   WHERE start_time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) AND host=20;

I'd like to modify the value host like this

> host='$1

but I have a little trouble, below there is a simple script:

```
    test="$(sshpass  -p ,password>  ssh -T <my_host>@$1  <<'ENDSSH'
    mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/my.conf mybman
    SELECT * FROM my.backup WHERE start_time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND host=20;
ENDSSH
)"

echo  $test

result=$(echo $test | cut -d " " -f 8)

EXITCODE=$result

echo $EXITCODE

if [ $EXITCODE == "SUCCESS" ] ; then
    echo "OK - to connect ($1)"
    exit 0
elif [ -z $test ] ; then
    echo "Critical to  connect ($1)"
    exit 2
else
    exit $EXITCODE
fi
exit
```

Any ideas how can we create this kind of variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When used within double-quotes, the dollar-sign would normally have to be back-slashed (\\), as in "\$1" - if you mean it to be literal '$1' passed to SQL and not a shell variable.

Comment: If you are wanting to use the shell variable, you may want to try the long form instead "... AND host=${1};".

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the shell variable, however I have already used before that syntax  AND host=${1};